Elasticsearch [size] query malformed, no start_object after query name'
I have a query I was using in Postman.  It is:
    { "size": 1, "sort": { "event_date": "desc"}, "query": { "match_all": {} } }
This returns the latest date in event_date for everything ingested and performs just like I want it to.
When I go to Python, I get the error though:

elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, 'parsing_exception', '[size] query malformed, no start_object after query name')

The call:
last_date_query = {
   "size": 1,
   "sort": { "event_date": "desc"},
   "query": {
      "match_all": {}
   }
}

if es is None:
    es = connect()

search_result = es.search(index=index, query = last_date_query)

How do I get the same query results when calling elasticsearch from python for my rather simple query?
I tried the above code in Python.

The query argument should only contain the query part, size and sort are other parameters to the search function.
You need to do it this way
sort = { "event_date": "desc"}
last_date_query = {
   "match_all": {}
}

if es is None:
    es = connect()

search_result = es.search(index=index, query = last_date_query, size = 1, sort = sort)

